# Getting a "this.is is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a "Sign Up" form for my new website, but got a problem with a jQuery/JS function that is supposed to check for some conditions to be reached.

```
$(function checkform() {
if (this.is("#username")) {
var validchars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
var nameHasError;
if (this.val().length < 6 && this.val().length > 26) {
  nameHasError = true;
  this.parent("div").addClass("has-error");
} else if (!(validchars.test(this).val())) {
  nameHasError = true;
  this.parent("div").addClass("has-error");
} else {
  nameHasError = false;
  this.parent("div").removeClass("has-error");
};
} else if (this.is("#password")) {
var passHasError;
if (this.val().length < 5 && this.val().length > 45) {
  passHasError = true;
  this.parent("div").addClass("has-error");
} else {
  passHasError = false;
  this.parent("div").removeClass("has-error");
};
};
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjz8r69s/) with HTML part (I'm using bootstrap on my website but preferred to set a specific class on the fiddle)

Best regards

Comment: In your code `this` is referring to the `document` object which does not have `is` method, also `checkForm` is local to the closure(dom ready) so on keypress will throw an error like `(index):89 Uncaught ReferenceError: checkform is not defined`

Comment: Why not have 2 different methods to validate both the inputs and use jQuery to register the event handlers

Comment: I guess that the `this` issue is solved, but still got a problem that I don't understand with my function as it's "undefined"

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fjz8r69s/8/)

Comment: where is `a` defined? see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code

- You have defined the `checkForm` in `$()`, so the function will be available only inside the dom ready handler, so your `onkeypress` will throw an error
- When dom ready handler invokes the function `this` will be the document object which does not have the `is` function
- The character size validation should use `||` not `&&`

So, ti will be better to use a jQuery event handler with both the fields having their own validation function like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#username').on('keypress', function() {
    var validchars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
    var nameHasError = false;
    var $this = $(this),
      value = this.value;
    if (value.length < 6 || value.length > 26) {
      nameHasError = true;
    } else if (!validchars.test(value)) {
      nameHasError = true;
    };
    $this.parent("div").toggleClass("has-error", nameHasError);
  });
  $('#password').on('keypress', function() {
    var passHasError = false;
    var $this = $(this),
      value = this.value;
    if (value.length < 5 || value.length > 45) {
      passHasError = true;
    };
    $this.parent("div").toggleClass("has-error", passHasError);
  });
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  background-color: red;
}
.has-success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Between 6 and 26 characters">
    <span id="unameError"></span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <span id="passError"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm quite new at JS/jQuery so I'll try to understand the whole code before applying it.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing vanilla javascript with jquery syntax. `this.is('#username')` is not javascript.

Use `this.id == "username"` (vanilla js)  instead

OR

`$(this).is('#username')` (jquery)

Take care with the **scope** in your functions

Comment: the function is wrapped in `$()` mean that it's executed on dom ready ... so `this` is actually `document`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkform() {
  if ($(this).is("#username")) {
    var validchars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
    var nameHasError;
    if ($(this).val().length < 6 || $(this).val().length > 26) {
      nameHasError = true;
      $(this).parent("div").addClass("has-error");
    } else if (!(validchars.test($(this).val()))) {
      nameHasError = true;
      $(this).parent("div").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
      nameHasError = false;
      $(this).parent("div").removeClass("has-error");
    };
  } else if ($(this).is("#password")) {
    var passHasError;
    if ($(this).val().length < 5 || $(this).val().length > 45) {
      passHasError = true;
      $(this).parent("div").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
      passHasError = false;
      $(this).parent("div").removeClass("has-error");
    };
  };
}

$(function () {
 $('input').on('keyup', checkform);
})
```

```css
.has-error {
  background-color: red;
}

.has-success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Between 6 and 26 characters">
    <span id="unameError"></span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"  placeholder="Password">
    <span id="passError"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```